# Playa 4.4.2 MSM - No entries exist for this related channel

Tags: playa, multi-site-manager

After upgrading to Playa 4.4.2 on ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 (Big client and quite reluctant to update to 2.6 until any issues are ironed out) we started getting "No entries exist for this related channel" messages on all fields that linked content from different sites through MSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source I found that changing lines `1762` and `1805` to

```
'site_id' => (isset($this->settings['sites']) ? $this->settings['sites'] : null)
```

Solved this issue for now.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for reporting this. I'll get this to the team.

Answer (score 1):

For Playa 4.4.3, the lines to update in ft.playa.php is 1888 and 1931.

Old:

```
'site_id' => (isset($this->settings['site_id']) ? $this->settings['site_id'] : null)
```

New:

```
'site_id' => (isset($this->settings['sites']) ? $this->settings['sites'] : null)
```