# Playa 4.4.3 no longer relating to other site

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, multi-site-manager, v2.5.5

I upgraded to 4.4.3 from 4.3.3. EE 2.5.5

I have an MSM install where I am relating the content of 1 field on one site to the content of another field on another site.

4.3.3 works great. Upgrade to 4.4.3 and I get the error: "No entries exist for this related channel." on the custom field when trying to publish a new entry.

I rolled back to 4.3.3 and I can use Playa in this custom field again.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Further searching in StackExchange found this related post: [Playa 4.4.2 MSM - No entries exist for this related channel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9889/playa-4-4-2-msm-no-entries-exist-for-this-related-channel)

I applied the hack and Playa works for me now.

Comment: Hi Marc - thanks for coming back to post your solution, it will be helpful to others. As this website is a community resource, if you wish to make an official request for the bug to be fixed you should contact P&T directly (via email).